# Want to retrieve specfic data from the result of a .jsp page using php

Tags: php, xml, jsp

This is my first ever question here.
I have following code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(3000);
$url= "https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?   msisdn=xxxx&password=xxxx";
print_r(get_data($url));

function get_data($url)
{
 $ch = curl_init();
 $timeout = 5;
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
}
?>
```

but unfortunately it's not giving any response. Just a blank page.

I want to get the response in XML and find the `<data>` value only.
While accessing the URL in browser directly its gives following response:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<corpsms>
  <command>Auth_request</command>
  <data>e8570f2482444d0ca50b76727d01a846</data>
  <response>OK</response>
</corpsms>
```

Please respond with some solution......

Comment: did you notice you have some spaces between _auth.jsp?_   and _msisdn_ ?

Comment: You should remove the spaces in `$url`.

Comment: I have removed those spaces but it still does not work